# Grails internationalization using messages.properties odd behavior

Tags: grails, taglib

I'm attempting to use the `<g:message>` tag, however, I keep getting the following error:

> org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <sitemesh:wrapTitleTag>: Error executing tag <g:message>: null

It seems it cannot find the messages.properties file even though it exists, and has all of the message codes filled in. I've simplified it to a single message code and it only breaks if I have the `<g:message>` tag included.

I am using the Grails mail plugin v1.0.7. It seems to be failing in the MailMessageContentRender class. Here's a snippet:

```
MailMessageContentRender render(Writer out, String templateName, model, locale, String pluginName = null) {
    RenderEnvironment.with(grailsApplication.mainContext, out, locale) { env ->
        Template template = createTemplate(templateName, env.controllerName, pluginName)
        if (model instanceof Map) {
            try{
                Writable writable = template.make(model)
                writable.writeTo(out) //This is where the exception is thrown.
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e.toString())
            }
        } else {
            template.make().writeTo(out)
        }

        new MailMessageContentRender(out, template.metaInfo.contentType)
    }
}
```

And here's a quick template I'm trying to use:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><g:message code="message.myproject.title"/></title>
        <meta name="layout" content="main" />
    </head>
    <body>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, the variables out, templateName, model, locale, and pluginName are not null when this exception is thrown.

Comment: Have you checked to see if there are any issues with Sitemesh and the message tag?